# System.Windows.Forms.Form has thrown an error in the designer .PNG image file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

From nowhere my form's design does not load anymore. I am getting an error that says that it cannot load some .png images. If I run my project all goes very well, but If I want to change something in Design Mode, this does not load. No matter what image I choose the error is still the same, but for other image.

**This is my error and the stack trace**
[image]

**And this is my code in cmbSpeedProfile2**

```
private void cmbSpeedProfile2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SignalType signalChosed = (SignalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SignalType), cmbSpeedProfile2.SelectedIndex != 0 ? cmbSpeedProfile2.SelectedItem.ToString() : SignalType.Sine.ToString());

        switch (signalChosed)
        {
            case SignalType.Sine:
                pbSpeedProfile2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"sine.png");
                pbSpeedProfile2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                break;
            case SignalType.Ramp:
                pbSpeedProfile2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"ramp.png");
                pbSpeedProfile2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                break;
            case SignalType.Linear:
                pbSpeedProfile2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"linear.png");
                pbSpeedProfile2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                break;
            case SignalType.Pulse:
                pbSpeedProfile2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"pulse.png");
                pbSpeedProfile2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SpeedProfile2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbSpeedProfile2.Items.Add("Select");
        foreach (string item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(SignalType)))
            cmbSpeedProfile2.Items.Add(item);
        cmbSpeedProfile2.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your Load event handler also runs at design-time.  That makes the code brittle, the PNG file is not so likely to be present in the default directory while this code is still running inside VS.  Beyond the universal mistake of hoping the Environment.DefaultDirectory is set correctly, consider that using a file is not the best approach in general.  You'd almost always favor a resource instead.

Comment: http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html

Comment: Can you share designer file code that it is complaining for?

Answer (score 0):

Check in designer code available in designer.cs file of that form, possibly it is trying to load a .PNG format file which it is unable to locate.

Comment: I checked, I do not have any .png file loading. The files loads only on SelectIndexChanged event of combobox and the images exist in debug folder